# Create an address book using a linked list

Tags: c, linked-list, segmentation-fault

I opened a thread yesterday asking about how I should proceed. Here is what I've got so far (sorry for the language, the program will be in Albanian but I'm sure you are getting the point).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void regjistrim();
void kerkim();
void modifikim();
void fshirje();
void rradhitje();
void display();
void load();

#define EMRI 50
#define MBIEMRI 50
#define ID 20
#define TEL 20
#define EMAIL 25

typedef struct node
{
    char emri[EMRI];
    char mbiemri[MBIEMRI];
    char id[ID];
    char tel[TEL];
    char email[EMAIL];
    struct node* next;
} node;

FILE* addressbook;
node* mynode;
node* curr;

int main(void)
{
    char input[2];
    int choice;

    load();

    printf("----------------ADDRESS BOOK----------------");
    printf("\n\n\t1 - Regjistrimi i ri\n");
    printf("\n\t2 - Kerkim\n");
    printf("\n\t3 - Modifikim\n");
    printf("\n\t4 - Fshirje\n");
    printf("\n\t5 - Rradhitje\n");
    printf("\n\t6 - Afishim i address book\n");
    printf("\n\t0 - Exit\n");

    fgets(input, 4, stdin);
    sscanf(input, "%d", &choice);

    while (choice < 0 || choice > 6)
    {
        printf("\nShtypni nje numer nga 0 - 6: \n");
        fgets(input, 4, stdin);
        sscanf(input, "%d", &choice);
    }

    switch (choice)
    {
        case 1:
            regjistrim();
            break;
        case 2:
            kerkim();
            break;
        case 3:
            modifikim();
            break;
        case 4:
            fshirje();
            break;
        case 5:
            rradhitje();
            break;
        case 6:
            display();
            break;
        case 0:
            exit(0);
            break;
    }

    return 0;
}

void load()
{
    addressbook = fopen("Addressbook.txt", "r");

    if (addressbook == NULL)
        printf("Could not open file.");

    node* mynode = malloc(sizeof(node));

    while (fscanf(addressbook, "%s %s %s %s %s", mynode->emri, mynode->mbiemri, mynode->id, mynode->tel, mynode->email) != EOF)
    {
        node* mynode = malloc(sizeof(node));
        mynode = mynode->next;
    }
    mynode = curr;
}


//Regjistron nje qytetar ne addressbook
void regjistrim()
{
    char input[2];
    char answer;

    do
    {
        node* newnode = malloc(sizeof(node));

        curr->next = newnode;

        addressbook = fopen("Addressbook.txt", "a+");

        printf("\nShtypni emrin: ");
        fgets(newnode->emri, EMRI, stdin);

        printf("\nShtypni mbiemrin: ");
        fgets(newnode->mbiemri, MBIEMRI, stdin);

        printf("\nShtypni ID-in: ");
        fgets(newnode->id, ID, stdin);

        printf("\nShtypni nr. telefoni: ");
        fgets(newnode->tel, TEL, stdin);

        printf("\nShtypni email-in: ");
        fgets(newnode->email, EMAIL, stdin);

        fprintf(addressbook, "Emri: %sMbiemri: %sID: %sNr. telefoni: %sEmail: %s\n", newnode->emri, newnode->mbiemri, newnode->id, newnode->tel, newnode->email);

        fclose(addressbook);

        printf("\nShtypni y/Y neqoftese doni te regjistroni person tjeter: ");
        fgets(input, 50, stdin);
        sscanf(input, "%c", &answer);

        curr = newnode;
    }
    while(answer == 'y' || answer == 'Y');
}

void kerkim()
{
    //TODO
}

void modifikim()
{
    //TODO
}

void fshirje()
{
    //TODO
}

void rradhitje()
{
    //TODO
}

void display()
{
    //TODO
}
```

Currently I'm getting a segfault at this point: `while (fscanf(addressbook, "%s %s %s %s %s", mynode->emri, mynode->mbiemri, mynode->id, mynode->tel, mynode->email) != EOF)`

I am mainly concerned about the `load()` function which will load any entries to the linked list, if there are any, before the user does any action.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: have you tried stepping through it with a debugger? if you're seeing a segfault, you've got a null reference. find it, figure out why it's happening, and you'll be on your way.

Comment: What is the meaning of `mynode` and `curr` global variables? What do you intend to use them for?

Comment: (1)and you have used the same name in the local scope of the two.

Comment: (2) `fprintf(addressbook, "Emri: %sMbiemri: %sID: %sNr. telefoni: %sEmail: %s\n"...` and `fscanf(addressbook, "%s %s %s %s %s"...` : The format of the file is different.

Comment: You may want to try verifying your file open worked, and reporting the error using `perror()` or `fprintf(stderr, ...)` on failure, followed by `exit(EXIT_FAILURE)`. Right now your error report is not being flushed to stdout because there is no newline, and you blindly march on to a while-loop that uses a NULL file pointer and consequently faults due to invoking undefined behavior. Also, your forward-linking read loop in `load()` is completely incorrect. If you want to forward-link as you read, use a pointer-to-pointer.

Comment: Since I spotted that the `fscanf()` was causing the segfault, I had obviously ran it in gdb.

@WhozCraig I added those lines and it seems like I can't open the file. What can I do about that?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you check out existing implementations of linked lists. Add helper functions for inserting nodes, appending nodes, deleting nodes, and those sorts of things. Once you have a working implementation for the lists themselves, you will have an easier time writing code that takes advantage of the linked list data structure.

Consider changing your `node` structure to include a pointer to the actual data and a pointer to the next node (instead of actually having the data in the `struct` itself). Better practice this way. You could even expand your linked list implementation to support any data type by using void pointers as "generic" pointers.

A segmentation fault with linked lists usually indicates that you are dereferencing a NULL pointer somewhere in your code (but is not the case all of the time!). Ensure that you are not referencing nodes that have been deleted or nodes that have not been allocated yet.

If you are satisfied with your current implementation, step through the code with `gdb` and set a breakpoint where the program is segfaulting. You should not have a hard time tracking down where the bug is.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a linked list try doing this
Replace this code

```
node* mynode = malloc(sizeof(node));

    while (fscanf(addressbook, "%s %s %s %s %s", mynode->emri, mynode->mbiemri, mynode->id, mynode->tel, mynode->email) == 5)
    {
        node* mynode = malloc(sizeof(node));
        mynode = mynode->next;
    }
    mynode = curr;
```

with this

```
node* mynodeLocal = malloc(sizeof(node));
    node *secondLastNode;
    while (fscanf(addressbook, "%s %s %s %s %s", mynodeLocal->emri, mynodeLocal->mbiemri, mynodeLocal->id, mynodeLocal->tel, mynodeLocal->email) != EOF)
    {
     secondLastNode = mynodeLocal;
        mynodeLocal->next = malloc(sizeof(node));
        mynodeLocal = mynodeLocal->next;
        mynodeLocal->next = NULL;

    }
    secondeLastNode->next = NULL;
    mynode = curr;//Change this line according to your requirement.
```

Comment: I still get a segfault when using `fscanf()`.

Comment: Try to replace !=EOF with ==5

Comment: Print something in loop, By doing this you can check that fscanf() is reading or not. For example You may try printing mynodeLocal->emri.

Comment: It seems that the problem is the file can't be created. When the file has been already created the load function is executed correctly. 
I don't know what's going on. The file is created correctly in the function `void regjistrim()` which registers a person in the address book.

Comment: Probem with load function is resolved? Now you have problem with regjistrim()?